# How to find distinct record form a table based on a composite key?

Tags: sql

I have a table as below in sql server 2012:

```
a   b   c   1   8   3
a   b   c   2   4   6
d   e   f   1   3   4
h   i   j   2   5   7
h   i   j   1   9   8
h   i   j   4   8   0
h   i   j   4   6   8
c   v   n   1   2   3
```

and i want the result based on distinct values of first three columns whereas rest the columns can be any single record like from the respective three columns:

```
a   b   c   1   8   3
d   e   f   1   3   4
h   i   j   2   5   7
c   v   n   1   2   3
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most databases, you can do this with the ANSI-standard `row_number()` function:

```
select col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by col1, col2, col3 order by col1) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```